# How to connect animations of element between QML files?

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I have two QML files, first is `main.qml` and second file is `Screen01.ui.qml` from Qt Design Studio.
I am not able to connect the property animation to main.qml file to control start and stop the animation.

**main.qml**

```
Item {
    width: Constants.width
    height: Constants.height

    Screen01 {
        id : screen
    }
}
```

**Screen01.ui.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    width: Constants.width
    height: Constants.height
    color: "#1b1b1b"

    Image {
        id: starImage
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        x: 350
        y: 190
        width: 100
        height: 100
        source: "images/R.png"
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

        PropertyAnimation {
            id: blinkerAnimation
            target: starImage
            property: "opacity"
            from: 1
            to: 0
            duration: 700
            running: flase
            loops: Animation.Infinite
        }
    }
}
```

I want to blink the image in some time interval in Screen01.ui.qml by controlling Property Animation from main.qml

Answer (score 0):

In order to control the `PropertyAnimation` from the `main.qml` you can either alias the `running` property of `blinkerAnimation` like so

```
property alias running: blinkerAnimation.running
```

which is a property of the root item in `Screen01.ui.qml`. Or you could alias the hole `PropertyAnimation` like so

```
property alias animation: blinkerAnimation
```

again as a property of the root item in `Screen01.ui.qml`. And then you can call `start()` on that property from within `Screen01` like so

```
Screen01 {
    id: mainScreen
    Component.onCompleted: mainScreen.animation.start()
}
```

Have a look at the [alias documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-aliases).

Another option without using alias is to define the `PropertyAnimation` as a property of the root item in `Screen01.ui.qml` like so

```
property PropertyAnimation animation: PropertyAnimation {
    id: blinkerAnimation
    target: starImage
    property: "opacity"
    from: 1
    to: 0
    duration: 700
    running: flase
    loops: Animation.Infinite
}
```

You can call `start()` the same way as in the second option. There are other ways to forward properties and functions to the outside by using wrappers, but the named options above are the most relevant.